# How to get Breakfast Club Ribbon? (Frankenfizzy - Level 9 )

Tags: bag-it

I am playing *Bag It!* I understand for this level you start out with two boxes of cereal, and as you destroy more items, the third box of cereal will show up in order to complete the breakfast club ribbon. However, I never seem to have space for the third cereal because I can't find a way to destroy the OJs without destroying the cereal boxes. Looked everywhere for solutions, this is my last resort.